# Why I get a list index error, if the code runs fine?

Tags: python

I have 7 txt data files, and I want to compute the standard deviation of the numbers in the second column, for each file.

I wrote this code:

```
from pathlib import Path
destdir = Path()
files = [p for p in destdir.iterdir() if p.is_file()]
for p in files:
    with p.open() as f:
        adatok=[]
        for i in f:
            adatok.append(float(i.split()[1]))
            
        atlag=sum(adatok)/len(adatok)
        
        elofordulas=[]
        for j in adatok:
            if j not in elofordulas:
                elofordulas.append(j)
                
        asd1=[]
        
        for j in elofordulas:
            asd1.append(adatok.count(j)*((atlag-j)**2))
            
        szoras=sqrt(sum(asd1)/len(adatok))
        
        print(p)
        
        print(szoras)
        
        print('-------')
```

It runs fine, but I get this error:

> IndexError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 6         adatok=[]
> 7         for i in f:
> ----> 8             adatok.append(float(i.split()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMfKv.png)))
> 9
> 10         atlag=sum(adatok)/len(adatok)
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Why? And what should I do?

Edit: This is a part of my data file, all lines are the same

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say "the code runs fine" if it ends with an error. What is in that line that you split? It must be different from the previous lines.

Comment: Maybe print `i.split()` and see what exactly that is returning?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of my data file.. the print(i.split()) returns what it should, lists from the rows of the data.. So I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you got a line without a space or a tab in one of your csv files. To be sure, just do some exception handling:

```py
import sys
from math import sqrt
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    destdir = Path()
    files = [p for p in destdir.iterdir() if p.is_file()]

    for p in files:
        with p.open() as f:
            adatok = []
            for line_no, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
                try:
                    adatok.append(float(line.split()[1]))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Exception '{e}' in line {line_no} of file '{p}' reading '{line.strip()}'")
                    sys.exit(-1)

        atlag = sum(adatok) / len(adatok)

        elofordulas = []
        for j in adatok:
            if j not in elofordulas:
                elofordulas.append(j)

        asd1 = []

        for j in elofordulas:
            asd1.append(adatok.count(j) * ((atlag - j) ** 2))

        szoras = sqrt(sum(asd1) / len(adatok))

        print(p)
        print(szoras)
        print('-------')
```

**Update:** We found that the stack trace was a bit misleading. The real mistake was that `files` contained all files in the current folder. This, of course, included the Python script itself.

Lesson learned: When parsing multiple data file, proper exception handling is important.

With the proposed exception handling, the error would have been something like
`Exception 'list index out of range' in line 1 of file 'script.python' reading 'import'` making it more obvious, where to look for the mistake.

Comment: I dont have "," in my data files, I uploaded a picture of what I have

Comment: sorry, already updated the response. I should have said: "a line without the needed delimiter". that is a space in your case, not a ",".

Comment: you say "This is a part of my data file, all lines are the same". I say: Somewhere in your data there is a broken line. That is why my answer to your question "And what should I do?" is: Find out which data line in what file is producing the error. You are iterating over all `files`. I guess, this also includes the python script itself...

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about I'm iterating over the script too.. I moved the data files into a folder, now I don't get the error.. Thank you!